# GIT and ignore files with commit

Tags: git

I am using GIT. And I want to ignore some files/directories when I do a commit.

I put in the .gitignore file this lines:

```
/@data/logs/tracelog.txt
/@data/logs/sc_notification.txt
```

But if I look in in visual studio by the files that are being committed.

I still see the files.

See image.

So my question is: How to ignore these files?

Thank you[image]

[image]

but for example. If I do this:

```
/@data/logs/fdce5bec-482d-45cf-8093-5d8c83f2e726tracelog.txt
```

I will not be shown in visual studio. So that works.

Comment: Where is your `.gitignore` located?

Comment: Git already knows about the file and has a history of that file, so just adding it to the `.gitignore` will not make Git forget about it. You will have to untrack the file explicitly in order to make Git ignore further changes in it.

Comment: Don't put complete path just put file name in git ignore ...

Comment: You mean like this: /tracelog.txt But this doesnt help

Comment: Thx all. I solved it